# Why is it showing trigger 'AICHAT.BI_USERDATA' is invalid and failed re-validation as an error?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle10g

```
CREATE TABLE  "USERDATA" 
   (    "USERDATAID" NUMBER, 
    "FNAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "CONTACTNO" VARCHAR2(4000), 
     CONSTRAINT "USERDATA_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("USERDATAID") ENABLE
   )

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_USERDATA" 
  before insert on "USERDATA"               
  for each row  
begin   
    select "USERDATA_SEQ".nextval into :NEW.USERDATAID from dual; 
end; 

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_USERDATA" ENABLE
/
```

This is my code for creating a table and a trigger but it shows that "'AICHAT.BI_USERDATA' is invalid and failed re-validation as an error whenever I try to insert a new value. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Have you created the sequence?

Comment: Re-run your statement to create your trigger again, and then post the output of `show errors;`

Comment: There's no semi-colon at the end of the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: It's a SQL syntax violation. I predict more questions like the first one will be asked, so try to use any DB IDE which will help you to start DB coding.